# Show/hide button with BooleanToVisibilityConverter does not work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

In my application I want to show/hide a button according to the users authorization level.
If the user is a team leader the button should be shown. If the user is not a team leader it shouldn't be shown.

I tried to resolve this issue using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` which is defined in my resource dictionary:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
```

Implementation of the converter:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5"
Click="TeamLeader_Click" Visibility="{Binding IsTeamLeader, Converter={StaticResource
VisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleMenu}" />
```

In my code behind class I'm using a dependency property to change the visibility of the button.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTeamLeaderProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("IsTeamLeader", typeof(bool),
typeof(MainMenu), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool IsTeamLeader
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTeamLeaderProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsTeamLeaderProperty, value); }
}
```

In the "loaded event" of my user control I initialize my property with `false` so the button should be collapsed.

```
private void ViewPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.IsTeamLeader = false;
}
```

But this won't work. No matter which value the `IsTeamLeader` property has on startup the button is always visible.

So can you please help me and give me a hint where I did the mistake? Is there a problem with the `BooleanToVisiblityConverter` or is there something wrong with my dependency property implementation? Or what?

Thank you!

Comment: hmm - never? ;) maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, probably this is problem:), try this in ctor: `this.DataContext = this`

Comment: hey man thank you! you're awsome :) that was the problem. now my code works. I think now I understand the problem. My property was not found because it was not specified where to search for it - so I think.

Comment: @kmatyaszek - write it as answer, Gery87 accept that answer (and optionally vote it up).  You both get points, and the question is marked as closed.  Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must just set `DataContext` like this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears (from reading the comments) that you have not set your datacontext. :-)

But to debug this issue in the future you should work your way back from the knowns in the debugger. Let me explain

1. Put a breakpoint in the Converter. If it is not being called the binding has failed at the source; such as what you found. If it is working, (and the return value is appropriate) then go to #2.
2. Make the dependancy property have a changed handler and put a breakpoint in there such as:

   ```
       public bool MyBoolProperty
       {
           get { return (bool)GetValue(MyBoolPropertyProperty); }
           set { SetValue(MyBoolPropertyProperty, value); }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Identifies the MyBoolProperty dependency property.
       /// </summary>
       public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBoolPropertyProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register(
               "MyBoolProperty",
               typeof(bool),
               typeof(MyClass),
               new PropertyMetadata(false, OnMyBoolPropertyPropertyChanged));

       /// <summary>
       /// MyBoolPropertyProperty property changed handler.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="d">MyClass that changed its MyBoolProperty.</param>
       /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
       private static void OnMyBoolPropertyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           MyClass source = d as MyClass; // Breakpoint here...
           bool value = (bool)e.NewValue;
       }
   ```

If the event never gets fired...you have a type mismatch between the data coming into the dependancy and what you expect as the type.

The above example uses a value type and that one is hard to mismatch so that might not be the case...but sometimes you have data as interface at the source and the dependency property can't convert the interface to its target object which is what it expects.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations. In the upcoming weeks I have a lot to work with dependency properties - so I'm sure that I will recall your tips to my mind sometimes ;)